# how to find the mm_struct and address for a physical page

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

I'm studying in android io using nexus 6 and lineageOS-cm14.1.

I write a kernel module which jprobe on mmc driver and get the pages every time when a request is dispatched, and now I need to find where the pages belong to.

Just like the parameter for page fault handler (mm, vma, address, ...)

Comment: I found the answer on LWN ~ [objrmap](https://lwn.net/Articles/23732/) and [avc](https://lwn.net/Articles/383162/)